# Generating random locations along the outer border of a .shp polygon using R

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile, r-sp

I am able to generate random points within the polygons using the package `sp`, however I am interested in generating points along the outline of the polygon.

For example, if I have a shapefile of a lake I can use `spsample(lake,n=10,type="random")` to generate 10 random locations within this lake. I am looking to do a similar thing but instead of generating the locations within the lake, I want the points to simply be along the shoreline. Is there a simple way to do this that I am just missing?

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to use the `sf` package, you can use the `st_sample` function. The trick is to first convert the polygon into a line, then sample the points.

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.0, GDAL 3.2.1, PROJ 7.2.1
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(415)

# read polygon shapefile
nc_p <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"), quiet = TRUE)[1, 1]

# Convert to line
nc_l <- st_cast(nc_p, 'MULTILINESTRING')

# sample points along line
nc_s <- st_sample(nc_l, 10)
#> although coordinates are longitude/latitude, st_sample assumes that they are planar

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_sf(data = nc_p, fill  = 'grey') +
  geom_sf(data = nc_l, color = 'red') +
  geom_sf(data = nc_s, color = 'blue')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This also equivalent to "Generate points along lines" in ArcGIS - yet this R answer not easily found through google searches - please is it possible to rephrase or add to question

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35559514)

Comment: i'm sorry - don't understand - how do we flag to folk that if they search for "Generate points along lines in ArcGIS - equivalent in R" they will be able to find this question?

Comment: No worries. Once you have a reputation of 50, you will gain a communication privilege to comment with the "Add a comment" link below the questions or answers. Here are some notes about the use of [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). But answers are not meant to be a space for comments.