# Generating point on polygon border with minimum distance constrain in r

Tags: r, gis, polygon, shapefile, r-sf

I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68987453/generating-random-locations-along-the-outer-border-of-a-shp-polygon-using-r) to generate random point on polygon's border. I was wondering how I could add a minimum distance constrain to this solution ?!
For example :

```
len <- st_length(st_cast(nc_p,"MULTILINESTRING"))
```

will return the polygon perimeter, and maximum number of points ,`n`, will be :

```
n = floor(len/min_distance)
```

But how the minimum distance should be implemented ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `type = "regular"` as an argument to `sf::st_sample()` like:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

nc_p <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)[1, 1]
nc_l <- st_cast(nc_p, "MULTILINESTRING")

# sample points along line
min_distance <- 7777
len <- as.numeric(sf::st_length(nc_l))
nr_of_poinst <- floor(len / min_distance)
nc_s <- st_sample(nc_l, nr_of_poinst, type = "regular", exact = TRUE)

ggplot() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_sf(data = nc_p, fill = "grey") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_l, color = "red") +
  geom_sf(data = nc_s, color = "blue")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>